# Posting data to sql server using servicestack and c#

Tags: c#, servicestack

I'm just starting to learn servicestack and c# and I need some help with posting data to sql server. When I test using swagger I get a 200 response but nothing is actually being inserted into the database and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Model.Type

```
public class Book
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int BookID { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfPages { get; set; }
    public int Isbn { get; set; }
}
```

Manager Interface:

```
namespace ServiceStackServiceLog4NetTemplate.Interfaces.Managers
{
   public interface IPostBookManager
  {
    Book CreateBooks();
  }
}
```

Repository Interface:

```
namespace ServiceStackServiceLog4NetTemplate.Interfaces.Repositories
{
   public interface IPostBookRepository
   {
     Book PostBooks();
   }
}
```

Messages.Request

```
namespace ServiceStackServiceLog4NetTemplate.ServiceModel.Messages
{
[Route("/PostBooks", Verbs = "POST")]
public class PostBooksRequest
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int BookID { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfPages { get; set; }
    public int Isbn { get; set; }
}
}
```

Messages.Response

```
namespace ServiceStackServiceLog4NetTemplate.ServiceModel.Messages
{
public class PostBooksResponse : IHasResponseStatus
{
    public Book Book { get; set; }
    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
}
}
```

Manager

```
    class PostBooksManager : IPostBookManager
    {
    private IPostBookRepository postRepo;

    public PostBooksManager(IPostBookRepository pRepo)
    {
        postRepo = pRepo;
    }

    public Book CreateBooks()
    {
        var bookCreations = postRepo.PostBooks();
        return bookCreations;
    }
}
}
```

Repository

```
namespace ServiceStackServiceLog4NetTemplate.Repositories
{
public class PostBookSqlRepo : IPostBookRepository
{
    private readonly string connection = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BooksDB"];

    public Book PostBooks()
    {
        var postBooks = CreateBooks();
        return postBooks;
    }

    private Book CreateBooks()
    {
        var newBooks = new Book();
        string query = "INSERT INTO dbo.BooksTable(BookID, Author, Title, NumberOfPages, ISBN)" +
                       "VALUES(@BookID, @Author, @Title, @NumberOfPages, @ISBN)";
        SqlConnection dbConnect = new SqlConnection(connection);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, dbConnect);


        using (dbConnect)
        {
            dbConnect.Open();


            var b = new Book()
            {
                BookID = newBooks.BookID,
                Author = newBooks.Author,
                Title = newBooks.Title,
                NumberOfPages = newBooks.NumberOfPages,
                Isbn = newBooks.Isbn
            };

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookID", b.BookID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Author", b.Author);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", b.Title);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumberOfPages", b.NumberOfPages);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ISBN", b.Isbn);


            dbConnect.Close();
        }

        return newBooks;

    }

}
}
```

Service Definition

```
namespace ServiceStackServiceLog4NetTemplate.ServiceDefinition
{
[EnableCors(allowedMethods: "GET,POST,DELETE")]
class PostBooksServiceDefinition : Service
{
    private IPostBookManager postManager;

    public PostBooksServiceDefinition(IPostBookManager bookP)
    {
        postManager = bookP;
    }

    public object Post(PostBooksRequest request)
    {
        var postBook = request.ConvertTo<Book>();

        PostBooksResponse resp = new PostBooksResponse()
        {
            Book = postBook
        };

        return resp;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you shouldn't have `[AutoIncrement]` on your Request DTO, you're converting the DTO to a `Book` object which is the data model you're saving, not the Request DTO. (It doesn't have any impact on anything, it's just unnecessary and unused).

Secondly, you're using [OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite) Data Attributes in your `Book` data model but you're not using OrmLite to insert the record.

To use OrmLite to insert a new `Book` in your ServiceStack Services you can just use:

```
Db.Insert(postBook);
```

If you also need to create the `Book` RDBMS table, you can create it if it doesn't already exist with:

```
using (var db = dbFactory.Open())
{
    db.CreateTableIfNotExists<Book>();
}
```

If you haven't registered your `OrmLiteConnectionFactory` with ServiceStack, you can register it with:

```
container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c => 
    new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connString, SqlServer2012Dialect.Provider));
```

See the docs on OrmLite project page for more info:

- https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite

#### Using a Repository

If you want to use `PostBookSqlRepo` to save your books you should configure it with your `IDbConnectionFactory`, e.g:

```
public class PostBookSqlRepo : IPostBookRepository
{
    IDbConnectionFactory dbFactory;

    public PostBookSqlRepo(IDbConnectionFactory dbFactory)
    {
        this.dbFactory = dbFactory;
    }

//...

    public Book CreateBooks(Book book)
    {
        using (var db = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection())
        {
            db.Insert(book);
        }
    }
}
```

Which you can configure in your ServiceStack IOC with:

```
container.Register<IPostBookRepository>(c =>
    new PostBookSqlRepo(c.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>()));
```